# Javascript Checkbox Function Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, function

For some reason, when I only have one checkbox item, the amount will NOT show up.  However, if I have two or more checkbox items, the amount will show up where it needs to.  Below is my code, please help!

```
function checkOnly(stayChecked) {
var lInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var fieldNum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < lInputs.length; i++) {
    if(lInputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
        if ( stayChecked != lInputs[i].name ) {
            lInputs[i].checked = false;
        } else {
          //Set the selected cost for this registration
            var selectedCost = document.getElementById( "tfa_2201[" + fieldNum + "]");
            var setSelectedCost = document.getElementById( "tfa_2202" );
            setSelectedCost.value = selectedCost.value;
          //Set the selected price for this registration
            var selectedPrice = document.getElementById( "tfa_2197[" + fieldNum + "]" );
            var setSelectedPrice = document.getElementById( "tfa_2204");
            setSelectedPrice.value = selectedPrice.value;
          //Set the amount due field
            var selectedPrice = document.getElementById( "tfa_2197[" + fieldNum + "]" );    // amount for class
            var setSelectedPrice = document.getElementById( "tfa_2532");                    // amount due
            setSelectedPrice.value = selectedPrice.value;
        }
        fieldNum++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your HTML.

Comment: Your JS appears to be missing a close bracket-- probably just a copy/paste flub but best to correct so everyone has the clearest sense of what's going on.

Comment: Also, please share how you are calling this code. We need a complete example to help you.

Comment: `the amount will show up where it needs to` what do you mean? Where to show what? once i've added the missing `}` this code seems to be working - https://jsfiddle.net/qajwaep9/

Comment: When there is only one option, the amount will not show - 
https://ibb.co/j7WCZc

When there are two options available, the amount shows -
https://ibb.co/ceD4fH

Comment: But yes, I did miss a close bracket when I did the copy/paste, thanks Alex